# JBoss5.X out of memory error

Tags: jboss, out-of-memory

JBoss crashed with out of memory error, how do I prevent this? I modified the values in run.bat but result is same.
"- Xms1024 Xmx1024 PermGen512"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a resource leak, in which case anything but finding and removing the leak will only delay the error, not prevent it.  [jhat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) & `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` will let you inspect the objects in your heap at the time of the OOM, which is a decent start to figuring out if you have a leak & where your leak is.

As for run.bat, the options you list may not be working the way you intend.  I would be sure to specify the "m"egabyte (kilobyte? gigabyte? mb seemed most likely here) suffix explicitly, and to set the max size before the initial size.  So, `-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M`.

512 megabytes, btw, is a big size for a permanent generation.  Maybe you meant kb?.  You can either use [jstat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) or add [-XX:-PrintGCDetails](http://-XX:-PrintGCDetails) to your run.bat to see how much permanent generation space is actually being used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to the problem explained here: [JVM: Solving OutOfMemoryError with less Memory](http://moaxstuff.blogspot.com/2010/11/jvm-solving-outofmemoryerror-with-less.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Jboss Version:Version: 5.0.0.GA, while running the application in jboss I have faced the out of memory error because of large data processing from application.

To resolve the same either you can optimize the code so that while processing there will be less data in heap memory or you can increase the heap memory of JBOSS:

JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m -XX:MaxNewSize=896m -XX:NewSize=896m

You can change the memory values as per your requirement.

If out Of memory error is coming with permgen space issue, then you can restart the server to resolve the same and you can restrict the same by changing the the memory value for the below mentioned variable:

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Thanks,
Ankit Adlakha

Answer (score -1):

Might be related to this.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7553

Apparently, when running as a service, JBoss might ignore -Xms